# How does the namespace of objects gets defined onto the 'window' object e.g. external dependencies via <script src=""> element?

Tags: javascript, html, dependencies, window, cdn

How does the namespace of objects gets defined onto the 'window' object e.g. external dependencies via  element?

I am using external dependencies distributed through CDN via the  element. I don't know what name to use to reference some of these dependencies so I console.log the window object to find it. What is happening behind the scene to cause it to name the React dependency as 'React', react-Dom as 'ReactDOM', or Babel as 'Babel'?

I also noticed that some of the packages from the CDN's had 'import' statements such as redux-toolkit which has `import from 'immer', 'reselect', 'redux', 'redux-thunk'` and export statements that '`export * from "redux"` and exports it's own functions. Does this implies that there is some universal accepted naming convention for these libraries on the global scope? How can I find out what a CDN dependency via  element is going to be named?

```
<!-- Babel (window.Babel) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<!-- react (window.React) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>

<!-- react-DOM (window.ReactDOM) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<!-- redux (window.Redux) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.2.1/redux.js"></script>

<!-- redux-toolkit (couldn't get it to show on window object) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@reduxjs/toolkit@2.1.0/dist/redux-toolkit.legacy-esm.min.js"></script>

<!-- redux-thunk (couldn't get it to show on window object) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-thunk/3.1.0/redux-thunk.legacy-esm.js"></script>
```

```
console.log(window):
```

```
{
Babel: {…}
React: {…}​
ReactDOM: {…}​
Redux: {…}​
_RTK: undefined​
_React: {…}​
_ReactRedux: undefined
​}
```

I have tried CDN sources and various versions to get all the dependencies to load properly on the project.  I also downloaded each of the dependencies and searched through the code to see if there were code defining the namespace but did not find any. I would like to understand what determine how the namespace for that particular dependency gets named on the window object and how it goes about doing so.